# How to print the last 15 weeks from specific date in SQL-Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to split the date week wise.

I want to know how can I print the last 15 week's date from today.

it should be week wise column, i.e. 15 rows.

Comment: What have you tried already? Do you have a table/structure already? Do you mean that you want a column with the first day of each week in each row?

Comment: yes, I dont have a table. I tried but I get last week of 6 days and all other 7 days. I want all weeks 7 days apart. YES.

Comment: What is the code that you already tried?

Comment: Add `datepart(week,@date)` and this will help you achieve the objective.

Comment: Fragment revised, more appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @COUNT INT = 0
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE(WeekDates datetime)
WHILE @COUNT < 15
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE
    SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -1 * @COUNT ,GETDATE())
    SET @COUNT += 1
END

SELECT * FROM #TEMPTABLE
DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE
```

Comment: If no table exist and I have to find weeks and show them in column then?

Comment: @Asbat just "SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -15 ,GETDATE())"

Comment: It is giving me 1 date. I need all the 15 weeks with each week on each row

Comment: Can you check why I have problem in getting correct weeks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060149/how-to-get-last-14-weeks-from-the-specific-date-starting-the-week-from-that-spec